# Can I change the default stats shown on my profile page?

Tags: overwatch

Recently I've been getting the current competitive season stats as default when viewing my career profile. However, I'm channeling my inner Danny Glover and I'm just *too old for this...* thing. I only play Quick Play and some Arcade modes.

Is there a setting for what I see as default or did they just decide that people only care about their hardcore, competitive, future esports star stats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment there is no way to change which set of stats is shown by default on your profile.